# Grails 3.3.2 domain classes inheritance issue

Tags: java, inheritance, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I've been migrating from Grails 3.2.11 to 3.3.2 and faced an odd issue:

If domain class inherits from a class from src/main/groovy - it's created and saved into DB properly at a first time. But when you retrieve it from DB and try to update the inherited properties - they are not saved back to DB.

Ex:

```
abstract class AbstractTest {
    String field
}

class Test extends AbstractTest {

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

If you run the following script in grails console it will print the correct values but if you check the DB - an old value (set at the time of creation) is stored:

```
import testapp.Test

new Test(field: 'original').save(flush: true)
Test test = Test.list().find()
println test.properties
test.field = 'modified'
println test.save(flush: true)
test = Test.list().find()
println test.properties
```

See https://github.com/ahlinist/testGorm

I use mysql, login: 'root', no pass

JDBC logging (logSql: true) discovered that no update query is sent to DB but the in-memory state (e.g. Test.list()*.properties) works as if the inherited property has been updated successfully.

Updating of ancestor's properties worked fine in 3.2.11. Couldn't find any answer in the documentation. What am I missing?

Comment: try annotating your abstract class with `@Entity` from grails.gorm.blah

Comment: @grails.gorm.annotation.Entity made my abstract class a persistent entity with a separate DB table. I just need the abstract class to participate in inheritance hierarchy with no additinal DB tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding of @grails.gorm.dirty.checking.DirtyCheck to abstract class solved the problem.

PS see the documentation: [GORM upgrade notes](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#upgradeNotes) (**1.2.13. Dirty Checking for Abstract Base Classes** section)